# When starting the react project, an error pops up "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')" Where to look for the roots of this evil?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to learn react, an error has occurred at this stage (full text)

Uncaught runtime errors:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1108:24
at updateMemo (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:22977:23)
at Object.useMemo (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:23553:20)
at useMemo (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38475:25)
at useCard (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1107:78)
at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:117:87)
at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:22188:22)
at updateFunctionComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:25070:24)
at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:26782:20)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:11780:18)
```

I can't figure out where I can climb to fix everything? I don't see specifics, neither the file name, nor the line numbers, please tell a beginner!

I do not know what to do

Here is App.jsx What other files are needed?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import './styles/App.css'
import CardList from "./components/CardList";
import CardForm from "./components/CardForm";
import CardFilter from "./components/CardFilter";
import Modal from "./components/UI/Modal/Modal";
import MyButton from "./components/UI/button/MyButton";
import { useCard } from "./hooks/useCard";
import CadrService from "./API/CadrService";
import Loader from "./components/UI/loader/Loader";
import { useFetching } from "./hooks/useFetching";

function App() {
    const [cards, setCard] = useState([])
    const [filter, setFilter] = useState({sort: '', query: ''})
    const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
    const [totalCount, setTotalCount] = useState(0);
    const [limit, setLimit] = useState(10);
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
    const sortedAndSearchCards = useCard(cards, filter.sort, filter.query);
    
    const [fetchCard, cardLoading, cardError] = useFetching(async () => {
        const response = await CadrService.getAll(limit, page);
        setCard(response.data)
        setTotalCount(response.headers['x-total-count'])
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchCard()
    }, [])

    const createCard = (newCard) => {
        setCard([...cards, newCard])
        setModal(false)
    }

    const removeCard = (card) => {
        setCard(cards.filter(p => p.id !== card.id))
    }

    return (
        <div className='App'>
            <MyButton style={{marginTop: 30}} onClick={() => setModal(true)}>
                Создать пользователя
            </MyButton>
            <Modal visible={modal} setVisible={setModal}>
                <CardForm create={createCard}/> 
            </Modal>            
            <hr style={{margin: '15px 0'}}/>
            <CardFilter 
                filter={filter}
                setFilter={setFilter}
            />
            {cardLoading
                ? <Loader/>
                : <CardList remove={removeCard} cards={sortedAndSearchCards} title="Все карточки"/>
            }
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you share code ?

Comment: Perhaps, u didn't get filter variable. And u should share code so that others can see it.

Comment: If you're making an API call and the returned data lacks an attribute that your code relies on, it may be due to a type mismatch between the client and server.

Comment: Please test the same feature in dev mode and share the code part where you are getting the issue

Comment: The error doesn't feel like something you would encounter on a development server (since everything is pointing to `bundle.js`). What command do you use to start the server?

Comment: "What command do you use to start the server?" 
npm start

Comment: And what command is located under `scripts -> start` in `package.json`?

Comment: "start": "react-scripts start",